# Obstacle Avoidance Sensor Data Using the DJI SDK (V4.3.2)

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I am currently working with the Inspire 2 & the M210 RTK. Can anyone help me in getting the Obstacle Avoidance sensor data output from the drone using the Mobile-SDK? I would like to get the exact distance reading from the object in front of the drone in an constantly updating value. Any code examples? I am relatively new to the DJI SDK so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into this, keep in mind that the distance you receive is not perfectly accurate.

There is a few ways you can access the sensors with the mobile SDK.

1/ Traditional interfaces using the obstacle avoidance part of the [DJIFlightAssistant](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant.html)

- Implement the delegate [DJIFlightAssistantDelegate](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant.html#djiintelligentflightassistant_protocol_inline)
- Implement the [didUpdateVisionDetectionState method](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant.html#djiintelligentflightassistant_updatevisiondetectionstate_inline)
- In the [DJIVisionDetectionState](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/VisionDetectionState/DJIVisionDetectionState.html#djivisiondetectionstate) object, there is a detectionSectors property which is an array of [DJIObstacleDetectionSector](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/VisionDetectionState/DJIVisionDetectionState_DJIVisionDetectionSector.html#djivisiondetectionstate_djivisiondetectionsector) which have a **obstacleDistanceInMeters**.

2/ Using the keys, you can start listening to the [Flight Controller key DJIFlightAssistantParamDetectionSectors](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/KeyManager/DJIFlightControllerKey.html). The block called will contain an array of [DJIObstacleDetectionSector](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/VisionDetectionState/DJIVisionDetectionState_DJIVisionDetectionSector.html#djivisiondetectionstate_djivisiondetectionsector) which have a **obstacleDistanceInMeters**:

```
guard let detectionSectorsKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightAssistantParamDetectionSectors) else {
    // failed to create the key
    return;
}

guard let keyManager = DJISDKManager.keyManager()? else {
    // failed to access the keyManager. You're most likely not registered yet.
    return;
}

keyManager.startListeningForChanges(on: detectionSectorsKey, withListener: self, andUpdate: { (oldValue, newValue) in
    let sectors = newValue?.value as! [DJIObstacleDetectionSector]

    //do stuff.
})
```